# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0: Are Powershell cmdlets available?

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am entirely new to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 and have been tasked to create some automation around MS-Crm administration.

To this end, I wish to use powershell. I have found that there are cmdlets that allow you to work with CRM (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328563.aspx)). But what I cant seem to find out is whether these cmdlets are only available in Dynamics 2011 or are they available in Dynamics 4.0 also?

I tried running "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell" on the server - but get an error message that the snapin is not available. So, not sure as to what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Dynamics CRM 4 there are no PowerShell cmdlets available. However, the cmdlets which are existing for Dynamics CRM 2011 are mostly a convenient way to automate the deployment service or to access the organization settings.

Most of these is also available in Dynamics CRM 4. 
Take a look at the [Deployment SDK for Dynamics CRM 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=2874D878-E28D-4530-A185-4DEE1FCDD12E&displaylang=en).

Keep in mind that some of the cmdlets for Dynamics CRM 2011 use new features of its Deployment Service, as for example the `Import-CrmOrganization` cmdlet. This is not possible with the Dynamics CRM 4 Deployment Service.

Comment: Thanks. Especially for the deployment SDK link.

Answer (score 2):

There are no official PowerShell cmdlets for CRM 4, but the Deployment web service is available for 4.0. You could code against that, or create your own cmdlets that run against it.

Comment: Thanks Matt - you saved me a ton of time

Answer (score 1):

Do you installed `the Deployment Tools role` ?

[Have a look to this post for more informations](http://www.langalaxy.de/2010/09/manage-dynamics-crm-2011-with-powershell/).